# prevent second row of lists from indenting

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields, listitem

I am displaying some icons and a short descriptor for each. I am using a list item to display the descriptions because I have a custom icon I am using to accompany the descriptor.

The icons display as expected, but as you can see the second row of descriptions is shifted right, not aligned with the row above (sorry the icons are so dark), I can't seem to debug why. All the properties seem to be the same.

[image]

```
            <?php if( have_rows('section') ): ?>

                <?php while( have_rows('section') ): the_row(); 
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                ?>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="mx-auto text-center">

                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>"> 

                            <ul>
                                <li><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></li>    
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

And how I'm styling the list

```
  ul {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
  }
  
  ul li {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    background-image: URL("../../images/star.svg");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 1.6rem 1.6rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, that we can easily test for ourselves. In this case, that obviously means that you would show us what the rendered HTML would look like - no one of us here has your WP setup and the data, to fully reproduce what you are dealing with there.

Comment: _“I am using a list item to display the descriptions because I have a custom icon I am using to accompany the descriptor.”_ - how is _that_ a justification for using lists in the first place? You only ever have one single item in each of those “lists” of yours - which strongly indicates, they should probably not be lists in the first place. (If anything, your whole _list_ of icons here should actually _be_ a list.)